# Результат проверки ломает вёрстку в профиле

Tags: дефект, профиль-участника

Путь к багу:

> *Профиль -> Активность -> Все действия -> Проверки*

Примеры:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Известная тема](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372732/339911). Исправят через 6-8 недель.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Ой) Пора бы мне уже научиться проверять MSE перед оформлением вопроса)